# Error:No such property: zipAlignEnabled for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error continuously when I try to build my old project in Android Studio 3.0

[image]

Here's my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.4'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your gradle file ? where is defaultConfig ?

Comment: please paste your complete gradle

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @AjayGeorge its with the update of Android Studio to 3.0. There are two options, Update the Gradle as given here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html or switch back to previous version of Android Studio, the later worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

For me the problem was with `classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.4'`. I upgraded it to `com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.0` and the error went away.

Answer (score -2):

Because AS 3.0 uses gradle 4.1，but gradle 4.1 removed the property-- ApplicationVariantData.

So, you can downgrade your AS or set

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

on your root .gradle file

Maybe you can see this http://dev.qq.com/topic/5a0cfef91d8190380176e74d
or this http://dev.qq.com/topic/59b272d9e0a78ea25114ed2a